# UITableView empty on load from XML array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.5

My UITableView is empty after my array is filled. But if i click the back button and go back in its filled.

if i load

`xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc] loadXMLByURL:@"http://google.com?xml.php?"];`

into the `ViewDidLoad` then its fine, but it takes a few seconds to parser.

So i have added that line into:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    if ([[xmlParser branch] count] == 0) {
         xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc] loadXMLByURL:@"http://google.com?xml.php?"];

     }
}
```

The reason why is because i wanted the XML to parser while the `MapView` loads first.

My mainViewController is set to have both `MapView` and `UITableView`; both are set as delegates.

in my ParserXML.m (xml has its own NSobject file)  file i have the table reloaded

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {


    NSLog(@"all done!");
    NSLog(@"stories array has %d items", [_branch count]);

    tableViews = [Maplocator alloc];

    [tableViews.tableView reloadData];

}
```

My Annotations are filled for `MapView` but not my `UITableView` but if i click back and then click the map again, its filled. ( but takes a few seconds )

Comment: Have you allocated the xmlParser before? Because it should you code at `viewDidAppear` should throw an exception.

Comment: Also, you call only `alloc` inside the `parserDidEndDocument`, why? I think you should initialize as well.

Comment: did you call [super viewDidAppear];?

Comment: @ipinak i added the init - No luck

Comment: @iiFreeman Yes i do have super! ( soz i typed that quickly ).

Comment: Do as the Answer below states. You must add the a data source delegate and a table view delegate. Those two provide you with method to populate your table view and to handle some touch events. And you must add the protocols on the class that will implement them and also add the methods inside the implementation of the same class.

Comment: and as i've said, i have done so.

Comment: dataSource - Tableview , delegate - Tableview . They are set

Answer (score 0):

**Things to check**

- Values are there in the array used for datasource of tableview when load first time?
- Tableview datasource and delegate methods are properly
  implemented or connected in IBOutlets?

If array is empty the problem is with parser on the first time loading

Make your call in a separate thread to avoid UI block and include an activity in the UI when parsing is finished and data is there in the array call for a Reload

Comment: All is filled. I use the same array to fill the Annotation and they show on the MapView. But when i click the UITableview which is hidden on load, its empty.

Comment: IF i click back and go back in, the cells are filled. ITs almost as if the array is empty because its waiting for the parser to complete.

Comment: Debug your code to see if the cells are actually filled. Also, try to change the `viewDidAppear` to `viewWillAppear`, but you should keep in mind that will hold the UI thread stalled until it finishes.

Comment: @ipinak if i change it too ViewWillAppear then its perfect, but waits to load the XML first then goes into the controller. I want to avoid that.

Comment: My Cells are empty on first run. its almost as if it  doesnt even run the cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Very Strange, as if on first load my UITableView function doesn't load if i dont place the XMLparser into ViewDidLoad. But if i click back and then try again its fine.

Comment: what is this    tableViews = [Maplocator alloc]; ??

Comment: Seems, it is empty, so if i add - `(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
   
    if ([[xmlParser branch] count] == 0) {
         xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc] loadXMLByURL:@"http://google.com.au//branch_locator_xml.php?"];
        
 }
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [[xmlParser branch] count];
    
   
}` then it works, but takes a few seconds.

Comment: Sort of brings me back to square one. I want the XML to load in background, and fill as it comes in. But i want user to see it fill. like i did for the maps. I just used a indication to show them its loading.

Comment: Please bare with me, im very new to Objective C.

Comment: @LithuT.V tableView is the name of my UITableView that site in my Maplocator.m file.

Comment: That's what Lithu T.V. and me was saying from the start. These are methods for UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSourceDelegate